# Input Simulator Virtual Key Code RETURN acts as spacebar

Tags: c#, keypress

I am using the InputSimulator package with c# and im trying to simulate the entry of the 'enter' key. When i do this instead of the enter key being pressed the spacebar is.

Alternating the keycodes.

```cs
                            .KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN)
```

I expect it to press the enter key however it presses the spacebar.

Comment: How do you know it's pressing return? Are you trying to press return in a field that doesnt accept return chars and the field is converting it to a space/what you're seeing is not the failing to press return, but a failing to render the return char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The program i was trying to submit the keys into was blocking the enter key. My solution of fixing this was to deselect the input and then reselect it and then use the enter key.